# Group by a list of dicts by two values in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to turn this :

```
[
  {'perm':'copy',   'id':1, 'name':'user1'},
  {'perm':'read',   'id':1, 'name':'user1'},
  {'perm':'delete', 'id':2, 'name':'user2'},
  {'perm':'copy',   'id':2, 'name':'user2'},
  {'perm':'update', 'id':3, 'name':'user3'}
]
```

into this :

```
[
  {'id':1, 'name':'user1', 'perms': {'copy': True, 'read': True}}
  {'id':2, 'name':'user2', 'perms': {'copy': True, 'delete': True}}
  {'id':3, 'name':'user3', 'perms': {'update': True }}
]
```

What is the best "pythonic" way of doing that ?

itertools.groupby looks like a mess and I don't want to load heavy packages like pandas for something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only use `itertools.groupby` if your input list is always sorted; in your example input list this is the case so you *could* do:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

[{'perms': dict.fromkeys((p['perm'] for p in group), True), 'id': key[0], 'user': key[1]}
 for key, group in groupby(inputlist, itemgetter('id', 'name'))]
```

The alternative route to use is a dictionary to collect permissions per user first, then producing a list from that dictionary:

```
per_user = {}

for perm in inputlist:
    key = perm['id'], perm['name']
    per_user.setdefault(key, {})[perm['perm']] = True

[{'perms': value, 'id': key[0], 'user': key[1]} for key, value in per_user.iteritems()]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> inputlist = [
...   {'perm':'copy',   'id':1, 'name':'user1'},
...   {'perm':'read',   'id':1, 'name':'user1'},
...   {'perm':'delete', 'id':2, 'name':'user2'},
...   {'perm':'copy',   'id':2, 'name':'user2'},
...   {'perm':'update', 'id':3, 'name':'user3'}
... ]
>>> [{'perms': dict.fromkeys((p['perm'] for p in group), True), 'id': key[0], 'user': key[1]}
...  for key, group in groupby(inputlist, itemgetter('id', 'name'))]
[{'perms': {'read': True, 'copy': True}, 'id': 1, 'user': 'user1'}, {'perms': {'copy': True, 'delete': True}, 'id': 2, 'user': 'user2'}, {'perms': {'update': True}, 'id': 3, 'user': 'user3'}]
>>> pprint(_)
[{'id': 1, 'perms': {'copy': True, 'read': True}, 'user': 'user1'},
 {'id': 2, 'perms': {'copy': True, 'delete': True}, 'user': 'user2'},
 {'id': 3, 'perms': {'update': True}, 'user': 'user3'}]
>>> per_user = {}
>>> for perm in inputlist:
...     key = perm['id'], perm['name']
...     per_user.setdefault(key, {})[perm['perm']] = True
... 
>>> [{'perms': value, 'id': key[0], 'user': key[1]} for key, value in per_user.iteritems()]
[{'perms': {'update': True}, 'id': 3, 'user': 'user3'}, {'perms': {'copy': True, 'delete': True}, 'id': 2, 'user': 'user2'}, {'perms': {'read': True, 'copy': True}, 'id': 1, 'user': 'user1'}]
>>> pprint(_)
[{'id': 3, 'perms': {'update': True}, 'user': 'user3'},
 {'id': 2, 'perms': {'copy': True, 'delete': True}, 'user': 'user2'},
 {'id': 1, 'perms': {'copy': True, 'read': True}, 'user': 'user1'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, Your missing a parentheses in the first example. Plus, the id is missing .

Comment: Built on you answer but replaced itemgetter with lambda to fetch both values got me the result i was looking for. `[{'perms': dict.fromkeys((p['perm'] for p in group), True), 'user': key[0], 'id': key[1] } for key, group in groupby(inputlist, lambda t: (t['name'],t['id']))]`

Comment: @haki: no need to use a `lambda`; `itemgetter()` can handle multiple keys.